# Безопасен ли такой подход в реализации подсчета записей, и какие есть альтернативы?

Tags: sql, база-данных

Допустим у меня есть две SQL таблицы:

**t1:**
*[ id,
name ]*

**t2:**
*[ id,
parent_t1_id,
text ]*

Стоит задача выводить количество записей в t2, по полю parent_t1_id.

Можно было бы реализовать SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t2 WHERE parent_t1_id = varId, но записей в t2 предположительно будет много, и запросы к БД для того чтобы узнать, количество записей будут осуществляться часто, поэтому каждый раз, *мне кажется* , пересчитывать таким способом будет сильно дорого по времени.

Пришёл к такой мысли, добавить в t1 поле count, и при каждом добавлении/удалении записи с помощью триггеров на INSERT и DELETE в t2, менять поле count в t1, то есть:
UPDATE t1 SET count = count+1 WHERE id=varId;

Не возникнут ли с этим проблемы? И какие ещё способы решения есть для этой задачи.

Comment: "при каждом добавлении/удалении", надеюсь у вас речь про триггер идет?

Comment: Да при добавлении/удалении собираюсь использовать триггер

Comment: `предположительно будет много`. Есть выражение: Преждевременная оптимизация - корень всех зол. Я бы посоветовал накопить данные, а потом уже что-то делать. Банально исчезнет требование подсчета количества, а вы это уже реализовали. `пересчитывать таким способом будет сильно дорого по времени` - если без индекса, да. А если построить по parent_t1_id, то будет быстро, пока индекс влезает в память. Триггеры также добавляют [оверхед на вставку](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/4647/198711). Ну и отвечая на вопрос, есть еще одно решение - использовать Redis, хотя идея с триггерами мне также нравится

Comment: *Не возникнут ли с этим проблемы?* Все обычные проблемы переопределённых данных. В первую очередь - рассогласование, причём штатной подсистемой контроля целостности неопределяемое. Если плюс-минус устраивает - используйте (не забудьте сервисную процедуру пересчёта в шедулер).

Comment: @Akina вы имеете в виду, что триггеры могут в какой-то момент неправильно делать инкремент/декремент, и количество перестанет сходиться? Я не понял вот эту часть: `Все обычные проблемы переопределённых данных. `

Comment: @TotalPusher Я имею в виду, что пока всё ровно и нормально, данные будут соответствовать. Но любой сбой может привести к рассогласованию. Причём ЭТОТ тип рассогласования не обнаруживается штатными процедурами (авто)восстановления и контроля целостности.

Comment: @TotalPusher *Я не понял вот эту часть: `Все обычные проблемы переопределённых данных`.* Переопределение имеет как плюсы, так и минусы. Данный случай - самый типичный и рядовой. Никаких уникальных проблем он не доставит, но и обычные никуда не денутся. Никаких особых плюсов он тоже не принесёт.